# Motion in vacuum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, vacuum

If we have a hollowed sphere in a vacuum, and its hollow space is filled with vacuum. In the center of the hollowed space inside the sphere is a ball.

If we push the sphere does the ball move? (prior to it being pushed by the sphere wall).

I have been strangely curious about it, so please elaborate beyond yes/no.

Comment: Why would the ball move - i.e. where would the force come from? I don't understand why you would become "strangely curious" about this, what makes you doubt the ball will stay at rest?

Comment: If you are thinking that the gravitational interaction between the hollow sphere and ball will be altered, the shell theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem ) proves that it will not,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Newton's laws of motion, the inner ball will not accelerate unless some force makes it to. It does not touch anything, thus in practice, the answer is that it will not appreciably move until hit by the inner surface of the sphere.

But is it that simple? Or would it be possible that two uncharged solids probably at the same temperature would interact in vacuum without touching? In fact, there are several mechanisms.

The first is gravity, but still according to Newton's later work, the gravitational potential in a hollow sphere is flat. This is quite nontrivial to prove, but it means that gravity will not make the inner ball move.

Another phenomenon will, however. It is called the [Casimir force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect), which attracts (uncharged) surfaces of solids. It is usually tiny, but scales with the -4th power of distance.  So once the inner ball comes close to the inner surface of the sphere, before collision *it will slightly accelerate in opposite direction* than the shell moves.

Comment: If we fill the sphere with oxygen instead will the push move the ball at all or - the sphere needs to have its own gravity to be able to move the ball that way?

Comment: If there is a fluid with friction, it will start moving with the outer sphere. Its friction with the internal ball will exert some force on the ball, too.

Answer (score 1):

For a hollow sphere of uniform density, with a spherical interior cavity with the same center as the exterior (a spherical shell, in other words), the gravitational attraction of the shell at ANY point in the interior is zero. This is called, fittingly enough, the [Shell Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem) and was first proved by Newton.

This means that, yes, if you push on the shell, and it starts moving, the object inside the shell will remain stationary until it contacts the shell.

You may find it interesting that the same outcome applies to electrostatic forces: a shell of uniform (fixed) charge produces no force on an isolated charge inside the shell.

Comment: If we fill the sphere with oxygen instead will the push move the ball at all or - the sphere needs to have its own gravity to be able to move the ball that way?

Answer (score 1):

The ball will not move until the wall of the shell touches it.

A freely hanging bell is a very common test for it. you push the shell of the bell and the metal ball inside does not move till the wall touches it. The bell sound comes from the wall colliding with the ball.